# Thymeleaf in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to use an HTML template as given below and set 2 values to it dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title th:text="${title}"></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-content">
        <h1 th:text="|Hello ${siteCode}!|"></h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the below code to set the values.

```
Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();
model.addAttribute("title", site.getName());
model.addAttribute("siteCode", site.getCode());
```

I want to get the new html file with the values added in the template variable so that I can store the file to s3. Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am able to store values in the template. But I want to get the html file with the passed values stored in the template so that the same can be passed to s3

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you explain what you are trying to do and what error you are getting.